# nuget modify text content file at installation

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I'm writing a nuget package which deploys some content files.

I'd like them to be modified to contain the version number and install path.

I found [this](https://docs.nuget.org/create/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) but it appears to modify only config and source files.

I noticed [install.ps1](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#automatically-running-powershell-scripts-during-package-installation-and-removal) scripts, but they look only able to transform the target project and it's elements.

What if I want to add a text file to the project:

```
You just installed package $packageName version $version in $installPath
```

transformed after installation in

```
You just installed package myPackage version 1.0.12.12 in packages/myPackage-1.0.12.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact `install.ps1` script is run after the content files copy. And It's run after the content files have been appended to csproj:

```
Added file 'myfile.txt' to folder 'mypackage\content'.
Added file 'mypackage.nupkg' to folder 'mypackage'.
Successfully installed 'mypackage'.
Added file 'myfile.txt'.
Added file 'myfile.txt' to project 'myproject'
>> PowerShell scripts are being executed from 'tools' (not framework-specific)
Executing script file 'init.ps1`
```

That means, you can edit whatever your static files from that script (accessing them) from the `$project` parameter~:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$myFile = $project.ProjectItems.Item("myfile.txt")
$filePath = $myFile.Document.FullName
$content = Get-Content -Path "$filePath"
```

I don't know the canonical way to  get the package version from this script, but it's part of the `$installPath` parameter.

Hope this will help someone